# Windows DHCP Server Priority

Tags: windows-xp, dhcp

How can I set the priority of DHCP servers to get a lease from in windows (XP)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, a DHCP client just broadcasts a DHCP request and accepts the first valid offer that comes back; there's no client-side mechanism for selecting which offer is "best".  There's apparently a [draft DHCP option](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dhc-sso-00) for setting server priority, but the draft RFC dates from 1997 and I can't find it actually implemented anywhere.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you could split your DHCP scope among multiple servers; is this for availability/redundancy, or something else?

Comment: does it mean someone can ruin my network by installing a dhcp server on his computer?

Comment: Basically yes but if you really want to get an answer search for similar Questions already asked and ask another if you don't find a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. First come best dressed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're so insistant on specific machines getting specific IP's, why not just manually assign them?

Comment: Or create reservations on the DHCP server(s).  I do that with my own workstation, so that it's got an address that's still in our DHCP range but won't change.

Comment: 'why not just manually assign them?'  That works for smaller networks, but for larger networks, you can gain centralized control using DHCP.  One example is to use a split static/dynamic allocation, where all servers/services are at fixed IP addresses and all workstations are dynamic; and for all addresses (regardless of static or dynamic) there is a reservation.  That way a machine will always get the right address with the correct network settings 'out of the box'.  Also, DHCP allows you to push routes, DNS, NTP, and other settings, saving time while reducing errors from manual entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two DHCP servers and set one to Authoratative, the other not. Only if the server designated as Autohoratitive would not be available would the clients take an IP address from the second DHCP server.